# Java: Simultaneous equations

Tags: java, equation, simultaneous

I've got this equation that I want to solve with a java application.

It looks like this

```
y*n-1 = y*n-2 + 1035 + [(n-1)^2 + (n-3)] * y
y*n   = y*n-1 + (n^2 * y)
```

So the user should input N and then the Java application should calculate how much Y is.
Is that somehow possible to do and if so, how?

Thanks in advance,
Michael.

EDIT:

Thanks to mprabhat, it looks like this right now but I'm still doing it wrong somehow..

```
   public class equation
   {


private static double solveFirstEquation(double n){
    double y =0;
    if(n > 0) {
        y = ((n -1) + Math.pow( n , 2))/ n;
    }
    return y;
}

private static double solveSecondEquation(double n){
    double y = 0;
    if(n > 1) {
        y = ((n-2)+ (Math.pow(n-1, 2) + n-3) + 1035)/(n-1);
    }
    return y;


}
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println("How much is n?");
int n = 0;
n = Keyboard.readInt();
}
    }
```

I tried to put the "void main String args" in the top but that wouldn't let me run the application.

Comment: it is possible, you should try and them come back for questions

Comment: what is Keyboard here ? Is this your own class ? Or are you trying to read from the console ?

Comment: @MocialovBoris, ah, you weren't sure about the difference between `[` and `(`. Specifically mentioning _that_ would be a lot clearer than stating that something "looks ambiguous", don't you agree? Anyway, you can now safely remove your comment(s) since it is no longer _ambiguous_ to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestEquation {

private static double solveFirstEquation(double n) {
    double y = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
        y = ((n - 1) + Math.pow(n, 2)) / n;
    }
    return y;
}

private static double solveSecondEquation(double n) {
    double y = 0;
    if (n > 1) {
        y = ((n - 2) + (Math.pow(n - 1, 2) + n - 3) + 1035) / (n - 1);
    }
    return y;

}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("How much is n?");
    double n = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(solveFirstEquation(n));
    System.out.println(solveSecondEquation(n));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, however I'm having some problems making it work properly, please have a look at the main post which I've edit with my full code.

Comment: Hmm the equation has to be incorrect somewhere.
By hand I get (n=3) y = 460

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `main` with something like

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("How much is n?");
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("First equation: ");
        System.out.println(solveFirstEquation(n));
        System.out.print("Second equation: ");
        System.out.println(solveSecondEquation(n));

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I can't execute "BufferedReader" and "InputStreamReader".
Do I need to add something in top of the code like some library?

Comment: You need to import BufferedReader and InputStreamReader like          import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this particular equation
One way is to convert equation to `y=` form

```
/*
 * y*n-1   =   y*n-2 + 1035 + [(n-1)^2 + (n-3)] * y
 * y = -1034 /(n^2-n-2)
 */
public static double eq1(double n){
    double m =n*n-n-2;
    return -1034 /m;
}

/*
 * y*n   = y*n-1 + (n^2 * y)
 * y = 1/n^2
 */
public static double eq2(double n){
    return 1/(n*n);
}
```

Fun way is to use **[wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Math.html)** !

- [y*n-1 = y*n-2 + 1035 + [(n-1)^2 + (n-3)] * y](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2an-1%20=%20y%2an-2%20%2b%201035%20%2b%20%5B%28n-1%29%5E2%20%2b%20%28n-3%29%5D%20%2a%20y)
- [y*n   = y*n-1 + (n^2 * y)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%2an%20%20%20=%20y%2an-1%20%2b%20%28n%5E2%20%2a%20y%29)